# Full Screen Iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, fullscreen

I am looking for a CSS solution that will let me to display a few horizontal full-screen iframes in one page.

I can do the jQuery myself, I just need couple of iframes to be in one page so I can click 'next' and the next iframe will be full screen. (So the iframes should be floated)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use iframeclass on the iframes to make them appear on top of each other, then use jQuery to set the z-index to show which is "on top"

```
.iframeclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

note: in order for height: 100%;  to work, the PARENT object must have a height set. ie:

```
body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Second note, please be aware that whilst this answers your question, its not how I'd recommend doing what I think you are trying to achieve, I'd recommend loading each frame's content into a single div with ajax as and when you need it. The iframes will ALL load their content on page load.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. Can you give me an code example of how to do it with AJAX?

Comment: Jquery handles ajax very easily and have several examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The code of @richsage works good but i had problems with scrolls in the page that hosts the iframe. To solve that i just added some "overflow" attributes in the body like: 'body 
        {
            height:100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }'